# How to change matrix multiplication so that scalars from left matrix multiply rows from right matrix

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication, broadcasting

I am trying to multiply two matrices, using matrix multiplication (I am not allowed to use any for loops).

Example:

```
A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
B = np.array([[5,6], [7,8]])
```

I want to obtain the matrix C such that:

```
C = [1*[5,6] + 2*[7,8], [3*[5,6] + 4*[7,8]]
```

I've tried many ways but can't figure it out without for loops :/

Thank you in advance

Comment: I do not understand. The result `C` above (if you add an extra closing bracket) looks like the result of regular matrix multiplication.  I.e. `[[19, 22], [43, 50]]`. This is what you get if you use `C = A @ B` or `C = np.matmul(A, B)`.

Comment: @Bill Based on the answer supplied below, the desired output is a matrix with shape (2, 1, 2) rather than (2, 2)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found the answer, so I'm posting it for other people:

```
    A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
    B = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
    A = A[:, np.newaxis]
    print(A @ B)
```

You just had to add a dimension to the first matrix